# Load function after onload is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to execute all commands once the page has been loaded, I am maintaing an array which pushes all the commands. This is being done via:

```
<img src='holder.js/200x280/text:name' 
     alt='name' width='200px' 
     onload='getPoster(this, name)'>
```

This is an iterative process and is run in a loop approximately 20 times.

I want that once this has been completed (page is completely loaded) and all the `onload()` events have been stacked into the array, *execute each one by one*.

I thought that `$(document).ready()` would let me achieve this, but it isn't helping either. However, using a `setTimeout()` function lets be see the ultimate result. But that obviously is not a good thing to do.

***getPoster function:***

```
function getPoster(img, title) {
    commands.push(new titles(img, title));
}
```

How do you think I should go about to load the images once all the onload events are stacked?

Comment: Handling "load" events on `<img>` tags is not reliable. If you simply wait for the document-level "load" event, that will be called when all the images are loaded.  The "ready" event happens *before* the "load" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a single threaded synchronous language. So basically instructions are processed in the order you write them up. Ajax requests are asynchronous, but loading things such as images isn't.

So lets say you have to call 4 functions `onload`, and then you want to load your images. It's quite easy, especially if you have jQuery. If you are not making Ajax requests or any other asynchronous actions, the functions will be executed synchronously, or one after the other.

```
$(function() {//is equivalent to $(document).ready(function(){
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
    functionThree();
    //etc
    loadImages();

});
```

To achieve what you want, the most efficient way I can think of is a custom `event`. Use something like:

```
$('#foo').on('completedEveryThingElse', function(event) {
  // So bind the event to whatever wrapper and then trigger it when you are done
  // loading all other stuff.
  // Now start loading images.
});

// Whenever you are done loading everything else.
$('#foo').trigger('completedEveryThingElse');
```

Have a look [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), the jQuery API for `trigger()`

Comment: Thats right, but my `HTML` calls (for example) `functionTwo()` several times, this happens when the page is being loaded. I want to call `loadImages()`, once the `functionTwo()` as many times as required.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of how many times `getPoster()` has been called, once the call count has reached the total number of images execute each command.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using ImagesLoaded plugin:

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<img class="posterImg" src='holder.js/200x280/text:name' alt='name' width='200px'>

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".posterImg").one('load', function () {
        getPoster(this,$(this).attr('alt'));
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but will the `.each()` method work once all the `.posterImg` are loaded? or will it be executed each time one `.posterImg` is loaded?

Comment: For each image getPoster() will be called